# Substring in Bash: Using Wildcards - why the order of the variables are mandatory?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working with *Substring in Bash* - Using Wildcards -

The following:

```
if [[ "$LIST" == *"$SOURCE"* ]]
```

works fine.

But just playing with (inverse)

```
if [[ *"$SOURCE"* == "$LIST" ]]
```

does not work

So why `*"$SOURCE"*` must be declared in the right? In other LP the order does not matter when `==` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the [`==` operator](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs),

> the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern

... so using `*` wildcards around it is valid. When you swap the operands, though, the `*` becomes part of the string you're trying to match, which is not what you intended.

Comment: In case anyone's interested this is one of the places where `[ ... ]` is not equivalent to `[[ ... ]]`. Consider `touch Zoom; [[ Z* == 'Zoom' ]] && echo yes` vs `touch Zoom; [ Z* == 'Zoom' ] && echo yes`

Comment: it's almost never equivalent because bash `[[` can deal with unquoted strings while `[` will break on whitespaces